# How to programatically remove microphone permission given to my webapp?

Tags: javascript, microphone, getusermedia

After I obtained microphone permission with `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })` and done everything I want with media stream how can I remove microphone permission and remove this annoying icon from tab and toolbar?

[image: microphone icon]

#### edit

After inspecting `LocalMediaStream` object I've found `stop()` function in prototype and it worked!

Comment: You found the solution by yourself, which is great! Instead of adding the solution to your original post as an edit, it's better to add it as an answer and mark it as correct. That way, the community knows the question is answered and accepted.

Comment: or just delete useless question :)

Comment: It's not useless! It might help others who have the same question. It's best to add the answer for whoever is looking for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend looking into [the permissions api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/permissions/remove).

You should be able to [revoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke) the permission, something like this:

```
const microphone = navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'microphone' })
navigator.permissions.revoke(microphone)
```

We can use `microphone` directly in `permissions.query` because it is a [valid name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/query).

Comment: [Please do not post answers with nothing but a link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I added just the link and expanded upon it.

Comment: revoke is now not available any more