# asking camera and position permission each page load

Tags: javascript, angular, web, position, getusermedia

How to force asking permission for camera, mic & position each time the app need and not save the choice in the browser.by default the choice is saved for the website.

I need to re-ask the user if he denied the permission and reload the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programatically remove microphone permission given to my webapp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52836836/how-to-programatically-remove-microphone-permission-given-to-my-webapp)

Comment: The problem you have is that the `.revoke()` method of the Permissions API is deprecated. As far as I can tell no replacement is available. So, you would be wise to rethink your requirement: you may not always be able to deliver it. And not now in Safari or Mobile Safari.